# Azure data factory store variable to file in blob

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I was trying to store output of variable in Azure data factory to file in blob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send the variable to Azure Function as parameter in the ADF. Then stored the value into file with sdk inside Azure Function.

The flow like below,using Set Variable Activity+Azure Function Activity:

[image]

[image]